# Symfony/webpack-encore копирование картинок основываясь на twig?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, symfony3

Добрый день.

В документации по webpack-encore я не встретил как работать с картинками в twig. Возможно ли организовать версионирование картинки такими же методами, как в CSS и JS?

Comment: webpack-encore предназначен для фронтенда, а для twig надо использовать assetic (http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял по Issues на GitHub — рабочего решения пока что нет. Единственный действующий способ это подключить нужные картинки через js.

```
// assets.js

require('../images/logo.png');
require('../images/basket.png');
require('../images/login.png');
require('../images/user.png');
require('../images/password.png');
```

В twig шаблоне использовать картинки также как и ранее

```
{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}
```

Только предварительно указать в конфигурациях Symfony путь до манифеста, чтобы подключалась картинка с хешем в имени для контроля версии

```
framework:
    assets:
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/build/manifest.json'
```

Тогда будет всё отлично работать. Единственный минус, придется все картинки используемые в twig шаблоне прописывать в ручную в js файл. Я для него в `webpack.config.js` добавил отдельный файл, который, кстати, не обязательно явно подключать.

```
Encore
    .addEntry('js/assets', './assets/js/assets.js') // Assets for images used in Twig Templates
```

Еще я нашел интересный бандл для Symfony https://github.com/mariusbalcytis/webpack-bundle но не стал в нем разбираться.